# Magento 2 customer session setAfterAuthUrl() failed to set redirect URL

Tags: magento-2.1, login, redirect, customer-session

I have created custom module for custom blog wishlist. So I have set authentication while trying to save blog into wishlist as below
Controller >> save.php

```
public function execute()
{
    $data = [];
    /** @var \Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\Redirect $resultRedirect */
    $resultRedirect = $this->resultFactory->create(ResultFactory::TYPE_REDIRECT);

    if(!$this->_customerSession->isLoggedIn()) {
        $resultRedirect->setPath($this->url->getCurrentUrl());
        $this->_customerSession->setAfterAuthUrl($this->url->getCurrentUrl());
        $this->_customerSession->authenticate();
        return false;
    }

    $requestParams = $this->getRequest()->getParams();

    $postId = $requestParams['postid'];
    if (!$postId) {
        $resultRedirect->setPath('*/');
        return $resultRedirect;
    }

    /** @var \VendorName\Blog\Model\Post\Wishlist $model */
    $model = $this->wishlistFactory->create();

    $data['post_id'] = $postId;
    $data['customer_id'] = $this->_customerSession->getCustomer()->getId();
    // $data['update_at'] = $date;

    $model->setData($data);

    try {
            $model->save();
            $this->messageManager->addSuccess(__('Post Saved.'));
            $this->dataPersistor->clear('blog_post');
            if ($this->getRequest()->getParam('back')) {
                return $resultRedirect->setPath('ideas-blog/category/home');
            }
            return $resultRedirect->setPath('blog/post/wishlist');
        } catch (LocalizedException $e) {
            $this->messageManager->addError($e->getMessage());
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            echo"<pre/>"; print_r($e->getMessage());exit;
            $this->messageManager->addException($e, __('Something went wrong while saving the post in wishlist.'));
        }

        $this->dataPersistor->set('blog_post', $data);
        return $resultRedirect->setPath('blog/post/wishlist');
}
```

`$this->url->getCurrentUrl()` has the current URL on which customer should be redirect after login successfully.

But I have created one plugin for another module which allow me to set redirect path after login :

```
public function afterExecute(
    \Magento\Customer\Controller\Account\LoginPost $subject,
    $result
    )
{
    $errorMessages = $this->messageManager->getMessages()->getErrors();
    if(!count($errorMessages))
        $result->setPath('customerview/account');

    return $result;
}
```

Above plugin will redirect to my custom account view page after normal login, but I want to redirect to custom wishlist page if set path as 'blog/wishlist'

So any idea how to do that?